SpringBoot - MongoDb Connection settings not working
I'm trying to set the timeout settings for Mongo connection in my Springboot app but they are not working as intended. I'm not sure if the issue is with the configuration I have or maybe my test is wrong.
application.yml
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/messaging

MongoConfig.java
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {

    @Bean
    public MongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer mongoConnectionSettings() {
        return builder -> {
                builder.applyToSocketSettings( bldr ->
                    bldr.connectTimeout(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                            .readTimeout(5500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                };
    }
}

To verify the timeout settings,

Start the mongodb service, then start the application.
Verify actuator health response - http://localhost:8080/actuator/health/mongo. It shows as "UP".
Stop the mongodb service.
Verify the actuator health response.

Step #4, I'm expecting mongo connection request to timeout after 2 seconds and return DOWN status response. But the app is waiting for 30 seconds for the connection to be established and then returns DOWN status. I see the following in log statements.
org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out

o.s.b.a.data.mongo.MongoHealthIndicator  : MongoDB health check failed

org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:93)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2932)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:581)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeCommand(MongoTemplate.java:513)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.data.mongo.MongoHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(MongoHealthIndicator.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37)

So why didn't the connection timeout setting take affect? Why did it wait upto 30 seconds before throwing exception?

One of the checks is to make sure that your database server up and running., and,  you are able to connect to the database from another client tool like MongoDB shell.

This quite simple. This problem come from the way Spring handles there bean, component. Try to set timeout to 2s and you will see it will need only 2. The timeout is reached because your code creates a task that keeps trying to get connect from MongoDB even when it is running or not. In somehow we can call this infite loop
